# Use Intl.NumberFormat to format square foot units

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) to format numbers with units and I have some units of square feet.

When I try

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { useGrouping: true, style: "unit", unit: "square-foot" }).format(56)
```

> Uncaught RangeError: Invalid unit argument for Intl.NumberFormat() 'square-foot'

The MDN documentation [links to small list of approved units](https://tc39.es/proposal-unified-intl-numberformat/section6/locales-currencies-tz_proposed_out.html#sec-issanctionedsimpleunitidentifier) which were taken from [a much larger list](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/validity/unit.xml). The larger list has square feet but the smaller list does not, so that all makes sense.

I see they allow compound units though.

> Pairs of simple units can be concatenated with "-per-" to make a compound unit. This suggests that it's only ratios of simple units, not products of two units.

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { useGrouping: true, style: "unit", unit: "foot-per-second" }).format(56)
outputs --> "56 ft/s"
```

Again, a link from MDN I see [this page](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-general.html#compound-units) which suggests this is possible with this `type="power2"` argument but that's in some XML implementation of this which is not Javascript not totally clear on the relationship between unicode.org and what's implemented in a browser)

Is there some way to get square feet as a the unit?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this ?

Comment: @psycho I did not. At the time I ended up just doing those ones a totally different way instead of using the built-in formatter.